# Network printer without port

Tags: networking, printing

I have old Epson CX8300 (without network port) connected to PC through USB, from the other side PC connected to Cisco RV110W router (without print server).

So I have a local network 192.169.1.xxx with 4 computers and a printer, connected to single computer. Is it possible to use printer from any of computer from current network?

Thanks.

Comment: What @Joeqwerty suggested is probably the best way of going about it, although bear in mind that the pc the printer is connecected to will need to be turned on all the time.

Comment: What operating systems?

Comment: System is Windows 7

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is. Share the printer from the PC and connect to it from the other computers. This article should give you the general idea:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457001.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @joeqwerty, you can share from the printer that it is attached to and allow other computers to print via that computer.

You could alternatively use a "USB print server". This has the added benefit of not relying on one single computer to be on. All computers can then print to the printer directly, using the USB print server's IP address.